# Can $\langle0|(\hat{a}-\hat{b})|0\rangle$ be written as $\langle0|\hat{a}|0\rangle-\langle0|\hat{b}|0\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra, linear-systems

I am studying quantum mechanics and dirac notation, and I am wondering if, given the operator $\hat{A}=\hat{a}-\hat{b}$, the expectation value $\langle0|\hat{A}|0\rangle$ can be written as $\langle0|\hat{a}|0\rangle-\langle0|\hat{b}|0\rangle$?

Comment: I think using hats, $\hat a$, $\hat b$, etc would make this clearer. A lower case letter is usually considered a c-number.

Comment: Yep, in Dirac original book this operator addition rule is mentioned as  $\{\alpha+\beta\}|A\rangle = \alpha |A \rangle + \beta |A \rangle$. Subtraction $(a-b)=a+(-b)$, i.e. it can be interpreted as addition of operators if we can perform negation of $b$ operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this follows from the definition of subtraction of linear operators. $(a-b)|0\rangle = a |0\rangle - b |0\rangle$ and likewise for the bras.

Comment: Except when both $\langle 0|a|0 \rangle$, $\langle 0|b|0 \rangle$ are infinite, but $\langle 0|a-b|0\rangle$ is finite.

Comment: @JánLalinský How can $\langle 0 | a | 0 \rangle$ be infinite? If $a | 0 \rangle$ exists, then its inner product with $|0\rangle$ must be a complex number by the definition of a Hilbert space, right? Is the subtlety that $|0\rangle$ may not lie in the domain of $a$? In that case, I am not sure how to define the operator $a-b$ so that it has a well-defined action on $|0\rangle$.

Comment: Let $|0\rangle$ be a ket with coordinate representation $\psi(x)$ that is the square root of the Cauchy distribution function centered at $x=0$. For this ket, expectation value of $\hat{Q}_a = \hat{x}^2+x_a^2$ is infinite for any $c$-number $x_a$, but $\langle 0|\hat{Q}_a-\hat{Q}_b|0\rangle =x_a^2-x_b^2$.

Comment: @JánLalinský Here we get into subtle questions about unbounded operators and rigged Hilbert spaces that are above my pay grade. But I would say that for that ket $|0\rangle$, $\hat{Q}_a |0\rangle$ is non-normalizable, and so this $|0\rangle$ ket does not actually lie in the domain of definition of $\hat{Q}_a$ (and likewise for $\hat{Q}_b$). So I would argue that $(\hat{Q}_a - \hat{Q}_b)|0\rangle$ is not actually well-defined. But maybe I'm wrong and there's a way to make everything rigorous.

Comment: $\langle 0 | \hat{O} | 0 \rangle$ may be defined as infinity even if $\hat{O}|0\rangle$ is not normalizable.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes. $$A|0\rangle= (a-b)| 0\rangle = a|0\rangle-b|0\rangle$$
And the scalar product, which is what happens when you combine a ket and bra, is linear. $$\langle0|A|0\rangle= \langle0|(a|0\rangle-b|0\rangle) =  \langle0|a|0\rangle-\langle0|b|0\rangle$$